# Simple jquery ajax request syntax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax request function and theres some syntax error im missing. Just need a second pair of eyes.. thanks

```
    function GetPaginationPage(array) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/get_pagination_page.php",
            data: array,
            success: function(data){ function (data) {
            $('.contestants_list').append(data);
        }};
            });
    };
```

Comment: try to use Object instead of Array

Comment: You have two extra semicolons. One causes a syntax error, the other doesn't. Use JSLint within JSFiddle or JSLint directly. You also have an extra `function(data){...}`

Comment: You have nested anonymous functions in your success callback, that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function GetPaginationPage(array) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/get_pagination_page.php",
        data: array,
        success: function(data) {$('.contestants_list').append(data);}
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem would be that you're rewrapped the function of the success envent, also you add a semicolon at the end of the function

Do remove the two function in the success event and the semicolon at the end, should look like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "includes/get_pagination_page.php",
   data: array,
   success: function(data) {
     $('.contestants_list').append(data);
   }
});​
```

**Notes**

A tip when you have this troubles uses http://jsfiddle.net/ and test your javascript code uising the button `JsLint` to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

You have function(data) twice for some reason, change it to this instead:

```
function GetPaginationPage(array) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/get_pagination_page.php",
            data: array,
            success: function(data){ 
                $('.contestants_list').append(data);
            }
        });
};
```

Hope this helps